# sorting using Array fill unstable?

Tags: javascript

I was experimenting with Array().fill() on Leet Code, and it was accepted with their use-case, but then I added another number to the array and it created an infinite loop.

Any idea why?

```js
function sortColors(colors) {
  const counter = new Array(colors.length).fill(0);
  for (let n of colors) {
    counter[n]++;
  }
  let j = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
    while (!counter[j]) {
      console.log(j)
      j++;
    }
    counter[j]--;
    colors[i] = j;
  }
  return colors;
}

const colors_1 = [2, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0];
const result_1 = sortColors(colors_1);
console.log(result_1); // => [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2]

const colors_2 = [7, 2, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0];
const result_2 = sortColors(colors_2);
console.log(result_2); // => max call stack exceeded error
```

Comment: That's not a stack overflow, that's an infinite loop.

Comment: Have you done some debugging? Did you step through the code? Did you try logging `counter`, and especially `counter[j]`?

Comment: No it doesn't, the stack does not grow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has relation with the `while` loop and the use of `!` operator. If it is `0` or `null` or `undefined`, it will continue iterating without escape. In this exercise is important to check if the counter value is `0` in a discriminatory way. Idk but maybe they used the negation operator cuz they was knowing the length of the array.

```js
function sortColors(colors) {
    const counter = new Array(colors.length).fill(0);
    for (let n of colors) {
      counter[n]++;
    }
    let j = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
      //here is important to check if the counter[j] is specifically 0, otherwise it enter in infinity loop.
      while (counter[j]===0) {
        j++;
      }
      counter[j]--;
      colors[i] = j;
    }
    return colors;
  }
  
  const colors_1 = [2, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0];
  const result_1 = sortColors(colors_1);
  console.log(result_1); // => [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2]
  
  const colors_2 = [7, 2, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0];
  const result_2 = sortColors(colors_2);
  console.log(result_2); // => stack overflow
```